# How do I discover the quality specifications of my laptop's soundcard?

Tags: audio, sound-card

This is a y510p lenovo ideapad. The product page doesn't list anything of value outside of the built-in speakers being jbl and it supporting dolby digital...irrelevant. I'm trying to discover how this laptop's soundcard matches in regards to a mobo's onboard card which has realtek alc1220. I'm unsure where this specific information is listed though.

Comment: The y510p has an [ALC282](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/303276-guide-for-installing-os-x-on-lenovo-ideapad-y510p/?page=29&tab=comments#comment-2171308) codec
(or see [here](https://github.com/acidanthera/AppleALC/releases) and search for "Y510P"). What do you mean by "quality specifications"?

Comment: I meant exactly what you gave me. How would I find or confirm this information on my laptop itself though?

Comment: In the Windows device manager my audio device has device id `DEV_0292` (Realtek codec on Thinkpad X250), I believe yours should be `DEV_0282` (and vendor id `VEN_10EC`).

Comment: "HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0282&SUBSYS_17AA1002&REV_1000" Okay so its alc282. But is the second part referencing anything of relation to the sound quality? I'm trying to figure out why the laptop's alc282 sounds 15-25% richer/nicer than the als1220 of my pc, I've tested with 3 sets of speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Windows device manager my audio device has device id DEV_0292 (Realtek codec on Thinkpad X250), I believe yours should be DEV_0282 (and vendor id VEN_10EC). – Freddy Aug 18 at 5:24